# UINavigationBars not showing when removing nested UINavigationControllers

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller

I have the beginning of one of my `UITabBarController` tabs set up looking like this, where the first `UINavigationController` is coming right of of my main `UITabBarController` as the second tab(index 1).

[image]

There was a `UINavigationController` in between the 2nd and 3rd Controller; I removed it because I believe I need to create a stack of `UIViewController`'s rather than nesting navigation controllers. All views should stem from one navigation controller, however, now that I have removed the NavController, I no longer have a navigation bar on the 3rd ViewController(running on my iPhone), what's the problem?

By the way I have tried using `[self.navigationController.navigationBar setHidden:NO];`
 on the 3rd ViewController that didn't work, and the 'top bar' is set to "Opaque Navigation Bar" in the storyboard.

**EDIT:**

At this point I have actually successfully set up my entire navigation hierarchy without nested `UINavigationController`s, but could not navigate, as it takes away my `UINavigationBar`s immediately upon being displayed, however, simply re-embeddings the views in navcontrollers re-established already existing `UINavigationItem`'s.

Comment: This problem has taken so much of my time it's not even funny, I'm clearly not understanding something conceptually or something, I have already read the docs on both `UINavigationController`s and `UITabBarController`s

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that there is a `Navigation Item` in the 2nd controller, if not drag one there from the component navigator. Then set the `Navigation Item`'s properties to test it (i.e., use a title, or add a button, etc.).

Comment: So I'm supposed to manually add the navigation bar when adding VC's onto a navigation stack.. in storyboard?

Comment: No, the navigation bar is added automatically in the `UINavigationController`, you don't need to add another one. What I'm suggesting above is to add a `UINavigationItem` in your VC, not a `UINavigationBar`. Normally this is also added automatically in your VC when you drag it in storyboard, however I suspect that you might have deleted it accidentally with all the deleting and moving that you describe above. Note that normally there is only one `UINavigationBar` in the `UINavigationController`, which renders its content by looking at the `UINavigationItem` of each `UIViewController` presented

Comment: Alright, I tryed adding a `UINavigationItem` to the second VC but the navbar still does not show up on the 3rd VC.. Also keep in mind that there's already a nav item on the third VC. It seems that no matter what I do.. I must have a `UINavigationController` between the second and third VC in order to keep the 3rd VC's navbar.

Comment: how are you connecting the 3rd VC to the 2nd one?